# How to set my form text box to default font?

Tags: html, forms, text, fonts

is it possible to set my form text box to default font? as you can see it appears black instead of my body text properties red? I need a html solution here instead of css/class tags. I ask cuz i need my from text bold and italic.

any help would be grateful. yummi

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input name="chatline" type="text" class="chatline" style="width:180px;border:none;outline:none;background-color:#2f2f2f;" value="Type Your Message" >
</div><p></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use inline css, simply add `color:red;` inside the style of your input:

```
<input name="chatline" type="text" class="chatline" style="width:180px;border:none;outline:none;background-color:#2f2f2f;color:red;" value="Type Your Message" >
```

Why the color isn't red? That is because you didn't call the `input` to give it a style. Now currently, it's adding a style to the body. Calling the input in your css will give you the opportunity to give it the style you want:

```
input{
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: can i add italic to this style? and make the field label disappear and i click and enter my text in.